# Regex ignores quote character

Tags: regex

I have this text -

```
[Event "F/S Return Match"]
```

This is my regex -

```
\[.*"
```

The match is -

```
[Event "F/S Return Match"
```

I was expecting -

```
[Event "
```

Why is the first quote being ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it non-greedy regex:

```
\[.*?"
```

Or better use negation:

```
\[[^"]*"
```

Comment: Anubhava, thanks for teaching about negation.  Or, at least, telling me about it ... I must see how it works.  It says: ignore the first instance of `"`.  Correct?

Comment: I have one text editor that is weak with regex, and it doesn't allow non-greedy.  This is why I'm glad to learn about the negation syntax.

Comment: @Smandoli: Yes it means match/grab input characters until you hit `"` in above regex.